# GLFW C++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake

i'm new in OpenGL and trying to create a window.
I included GLFW and GLEW headers, but always get this error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glViewport", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

I already tried to use g++ instead of gcc and vice-versa, but nothing helped.

UPD: using MacOS

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(OpenGL_Works)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(OpenGL_Works main.cpp)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -pthread")

include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/include/GLFW/")
target_link_libraries(OpenGL_Works "/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib")

include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/include/GL/")
target_link_libraries(OpenGL_Works "/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/lib/libGLEW.a")
```

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*GL_GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);

GL_GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers  = (GL_GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");


int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "miko learns OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link to libGL. You really should be using find_package instead of the manual include and link commands.

Comment: As drescherjm already suggested, try adding `-lGL` to your CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.